# Inner product of distance between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

We can define a 'distance' between two points $P = (x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ of the plane by $d(P,Q) = |x_2 - x_1| + |y_2 - y_1|$. Verify if the sentence below is a inner product in the plane. 
$$\langle(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\rangle = d(P,Q)$$

UPDATE: What i've already made

Positivity
$\langle P,P\rangle \geq 0 $

The distance from a point to a point is 0. [check]

Symmetry
$ \langle P,Q \rangle = \langle Q,P \rangle$ 

The distance from a point P to a point Q is equal to distance from a point Q to the point Q.[check]

Bilinearity
$ \langle\lambda P,Q\rangle = \lambda\langle P,Q\rangle \\ 
\langle(\lambda x_1,\lambda y_1),(x_2,y_2)\rangle = |x_2 - \lambda x_1| + | y_2 - \lambda y_1 |\\$

I'm stuck here, i don't know how get out with this.

Comment: What are the properties of an inner product? How would you verify them in this case?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your work and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Bilinearity,symmetry and positivity. I've tried and got the symmetry and positivity, but the linearity (even making each linearity separated) i do not.

Comment: Have you considered that it might not be an inner product? Try a few examples and see if bilinearity holds for those examples.

Comment: Yeah, the answer from J.G. helped me. I did not try before because the answer from my professor was that is a inner product, but i was confusing how do this.

Comment: For an inner product, you need not just positivity but positive definiteness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an inner product because it isn't linear. For example, the choice $P=Q=(1,\,0)$ implies $d(P,\,kQ)=|k-1|$,  which for $k\ne 1$ differs from $kd(P,\,Q)=0$.